# Implementing a MySQL trigger with a where condition including a count function

Tags: mysql, triggers

The requirement is to implement a trigger that checks an exception table for entries that meet a set of criteria, multiple times over the past 1 hour.  Basically we don't want to be alerted on transient exceptions.

This is where I have got;

```
CREATE TRIGGER trException AFTER INSERT ON Exception
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  IF NEW.ExceptionMessage like '%The operation is timed out%' or 
    NEW.ExceptionMessage like '%https://....%' THEN
    INSERT INTO NotificationLog ('Message','InsertedTime') SELECT 'Time out error',now() 
    WHERE (SELECT COUNT(ExceptionId) FROM Exception 
           WHERE CreateTimestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
           AND ExceptionMessage LIKE '%The operation has timed out%' 
           AND ExceptionMessage LIKE '%https://....%') > 10;
  ELSEIF NEW.ExceptionMessage like '%Error...%' THEN
            ...Next insert scenario with critria
  END IF;
END;
```

I think the issue is the count in the embedded SELECT statement.  The code works fine when it is run outside the insert statement. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem.  By adding a table (ExceptionNotificationMessage) to hold the notification messages, I was able to add a FROM clause to the first SELECT statement and that fixed the problem.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trException AFTER INSERT ON Exception
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  IF NEW.ExceptionMessage like '%The operation is timed out%' or 
    NEW.ExceptionMessage like '%https://....%' THEN
    INSERT INTO NotificationLog ('Message','InsertedTime') 
      SELECT 'Message','InsertedTime'
      **FROM ExceptionNotificationMessage** 
      WHERE (SELECT COUNT(ExceptionId) FROM Exception 
           WHERE CreateTimestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
           AND ExceptionMessage LIKE '%The operation has timed out%' 
           AND ExceptionMessage LIKE '%https://....%') > 10;
  ELSEIF NEW.ExceptionMessage like '%Error...%' THEN
            ...Next insert scenario with criteria
  END IF;
END;
```

Martin